# Recommend between workstation and tower server?

Tags: hardware

I'm planning to buy a computer for my office. What i want is a computer that strong, stability, can run 24/7 for hosting my website with tens of thousand people visit per day. Because it's placed in my office so i also want to use it to do other work of mine directly on it like Develop 3D Graphic, Autocad, After Effect...

The CPU/RAM usage is not problem because i will choose a strong CPU and buy many RAM for both my job can working without overload. The problem is just i don't know whether i should using a workstation or server in this case.

I've hear someone said that the workstation is not good for running web server because it's not designed for manipulate multi-connection at the same time in long time. And also someone say the server is not designed for graphic design so it will have bad performance when rendering graphic, it also don't have audio input/output line.

I cannot buy both workstation and server because it too expensive, so can someone tell me what should i do in my case ? Can i buy a server, and then buy a Graphic card, and than buy a USB to Audio device instead of buy a workstation ? Or can i buy a workstation instead of a server ?

Comment: Don't. Just get a dedicated or VPS server for running the site, and then use a workstation for...well, work.

Comment: @tombull89 some one can tell me exactly why i cannot do this ?

Comment: There's no technical reason why you can't host website (or websites) on your machine. However, if you reboot your machine, that'll take your website down. If your machine dies, that'll take your website down. If you have a power cut, that'll take your website down. You could buy a large HP server and put a fairly helfy graphics card in it, but server are LOUD and no way in hell would I want to use one as a desktop.

Comment: @tombull89 thank you so much, it seem that your answer is very valuable and clean to me. So the server can run graphic card and working normally with graphic software like a workstation, but the main problem is down-time and noise ? I have heard about the noise if i using a rack server. But what about if i using tower server instead ? Some people said it make very little noise if i using tower server ?

Comment: @user4835: Please, please please: Forget about this. Servers and workstations are different things software and use-case wise, not necessarily hardware-wise. You ended up on a site of pro admins to ask this questions and you got the universal response to not do this. Please, take the hint, because there is no reason to ask if you chose to ignore the answers if you don't like them. You don't need to buy a separate server. There are web hosting packages and VPS for a few bucks a month, so there is no financial reason to go your route.

Comment: @SvW Thank you so much for your answer, i already have a server running on data center. I just want to have a computer for my working, and also acting as a backup server when my main server go down for few day if it happen in the future. When it happen i will not use my computer for working anymore and just keep it running to prevent reboot and slow. I don't want to buy another server or VPS because it will cost too much money and the VPS can't strong to host my website and service. So is it possible for my case in technical/hardware reason ?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense at all, and your story gets even more nonsensical. You have all our recommendations of not doing this, and now I am out of this. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about this. Either you have a server or a dev workstation. Doing both on the same machine is a outright stupid idea and will lead to no end of problems.

Put your website on a real server in a real datacenter ('real' *does* include VPS or even a web hosting package, if applicable) and buy a workstation that fits your workstation needs.

Some reasons:

- Your office connection will very likely not be designed to handle a public server, with asymmetric connection speeds, and somewhat likely, outright bans of server applications in the providers TOS.
- The web site will be affected by everything you do on the machine, which can include reboots for all kind of reasons. You render an image? The site get's slow. An app crashed hard? Reboot. Site is down. etc.etc.
- Your workstation will not be as reliable hardware wise as a server. If you buy a real server and outfit it to be used as a workstation, it will be noisy and annoying (and takes ages to reboot).

I could add *many* more reasons, but please just believe me: It's a stupid idea and every experienced admin will agree to this. Being asked to do this in my job, I would outright refuse because it's unprofessional and would cause both the user and me no end of trouble and grief.

Comment: Can you tell me why ? What happen if i run my web server in a workstation ? It's just slow ? And also what happen if i run a graphic software in a server ? I'm not talking about datacenter - network -electric .. etc , just talking about the hardware.

Comment: It goes against every single principle and best practice of professional systems administration.

Comment: @EEAA i'm not caring about the professionality, i just caring about the performance and real full reason that against my plan.

Comment: Well you've asked a question on a site dedicated to professional sysadmin. If you want a non-professional answer, you'll need to look elsewhere.

Comment: @SvW has given you reasons. I do not need to restate them.

Comment: @EEAA i'm sorry

Comment: @user4835 stop being cheap. If you want to play sysadmin, at least play by the rules. The rule is *don't serve productions websites from an enduser computer*. [Get off the dime](http://www.word-detective.com/2010/01/get-off-the-dime/) and rent a VPS for webserving, you'll be glad you did.